# C++ unique_ptr and observer pattern best practices

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11, observer-pattern, smart-pointers

I'm trying to write a correct C++11 application,  and I'm faced to a problem of memory management with observer design pattern.

My emitter and listeners are owned by the same class, stored in a `std::unique_ptr`.
The code that I think to write should look like this:

```cpp
class Listener {
    Emitter &myEmitter;

    public:
        Listener(Emitter &emiter): myEmitter(emitter) {
            myEmitter.register(*this);
        }
        virtual ~Listener() {
            myEmitter.unregister(*this);
        }
}
class Emitter {
    std::vector<Listener*> myListeners;
    public:
        void register(Listener &listener) {
            myListeners.push_back(&listener);
        }
        void unregister(Listener &listener) {
            myListeners.erase(std::remove(myListeners.begin(), myListeners.end(), &listener));
        }
}
class Owner {
    std::unique_ptr<Listener> theListener;
    std::unique_ptr<Emitter> theEmitter;
}
```

Is it a correct approach ?

Comment: What is your memory management problem exactly?

Comment: I've read that use unique_ptr is better than shared_ptr, for ownership, so I try to avoid shared_ptr. In this case it seems possible, so I ask if it is the right way.
In other cases where observer and listeners are not managed by the same object, I don't think this solution works, right ?

Comment: @xabufr: That first statement is nonsense. shared_ptr and unique_ptr have *different* use cases.

Comment: @xabufr I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Why are you using std::unique_ptr instead of just declaring an instance of Emitter and Listener?

Comment: @o_weisman: Good question. Why use dynamic memory management at all here?

Comment: In fact I was trying to reduce compilation time by using more predeclaration, but you right, smart pointer are not usefull here...

Comment: @xabufr: I assume you mean forward declarations. They also work with references.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, forward declarations sorry.
But references are like pointer right ? I can't use them like stack allocated variables...

Comment: References are similar to pointers but are a very different language feature. Almost most importantly, there is no such thing as a "null reference".

Comment: I find that the lifetimes of emitters and listeners are often difficult to connect in a reasonable sized app.  My listeners tend to be shared pointers to `std::function`s (invokables, why constrain further?), and the emitter stores a `weak_ptr` to same (non owning pointer: the object listening keeps a `shared_ptr`).  The listener now has the responsibility to be well defined to be invoked during its lifetime: and you unregister by simply killing it.

Comment: @Yakk I don't think that the Observer pattern has anything to do with the lifetime of the objects that interact within it, correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: @o_weisman if the listener dies without unregistering, the next broadcast is UB.  If the observed dies without being unregistered, the listener unregistering can be UB.  So lifetime matters.  The above sketches a way how to make lifetime issues easy to solve.

Comment: @Yakk You are right of course, whenever a pointer is held by an object that doesn't manage it, there are implications for the life time of the object behind the pointer. This is not the main issue of the observer pattern however in my opinion and that is what I was trying to say.

Comment: @o_weisman except observer means both need to be aware of the lifetime of the other, which makes it complicated and bug prone.  Often code punts, and assumes 'X lives longer than Y', then manage X's knowledge of Y's lifetime only.  This is usually bad.  Due to this bi-directional lifetime management issue, any non-trivial discussion of the observer pattern should take lifetime into account, because it is one of the 3-4 hard parts. (others include deregistration/registration during triggering events, preventing notification cycles, and coherancy of state). Signatures are merely bikeshed issues.